# Basic script to replace image files in multiple directories

Tags: powershell, scripting, vbscript

I have a situation where we have several thousand image files that have become corrupted on our server (Windows 2008 R2 x64).  I have a working image file that I want to replace the corrupt files with.  The files must retain the same name and path (size, timestamps, etc do not matter).

So the basic idea would be to replace each corrupt image file with the working file.

I do not write code, only the occasional windows batch file.

Should I use VB or PowerShell (or something else) for this?  What will the script look like for this?

I apologize in advance if this question is too basic for stackoverflow.

Comment: How are you identifying the corrupt files?

Comment: The corrupt files are located in several folders.  They are image files (some jpg and some tif).  All of the files in each folder are corrupt, so I don't need to differentiate among good and bad files in the folders.  So something that would replace all files in a specific folder with the good file is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks see my answer below, using for should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a batch file,

try looking at the for command

e.g.

FOR /R  %f in (*.jpg) DO copy newfile.jpg "%f"

This should do a recursive search and copy newfile.jpg over the jpg's it finds.

It all boils down to how you are identifying the broken jpgs.

Comment: You might not want the Recursive /R switch.

Answer (score 1):

When I dont use a wild card for example

```
FOR /R %f in (broken.jpg) DO copy newfile.jpg "%f"
```

Then newfile.jpg gets copied to every subdirectory. If I use a wildcard ( *,?) the command works as expected. Is there a way to have this commend work with a (set) that does not contain wildcards?